# ffmpeg recognises MXF dv but won't encode to h264

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a DV file encoded as an MXF that I want to transcode to h264. Running ffmpeg against the file it reads ok and understands the stream but won't write the h264 file. It seems to get all the streams correct and I can confirm the attributes of video and audio streams.

I just don't understand why it won't encode? I tried to force a Decoder with -f dv but it complained that the source header was incorrect.

```
 ./ffmpeg -f dv -i camb_onitefire_050914.mov  camb_onitefire_A.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[dv @ 0x7fd6f4800000] Cannot find DV header.
camb_onitefire_050914.mov: Operation not permitted
Davids-MacBook-Pro:camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf davidmcsween$ ./ffmpeg -i camb_onitefire_050914.mov camb_onitefire_A.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Skipped opening external track: stream 0, alias: path='/VibrintAVFiles/P2 News Ingest/camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf/video.vid', dir='camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf', filename='video.vid', volume='default', nlvl_from=1, nlvl_to=1.Set enable_drefs to allow this.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Skipped opening external track: stream 1, alias: path='/VibrintAVFiles/P2 News Ingest/camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf/audio_0.pcm', dir='camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf', filename='audio_0.pcm', volume='default', nlvl_from=1, nlvl_to=1.Set enable_drefs to allow this.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Skipped opening external track: stream 2, alias: path='/VibrintAVFiles/P2 News Ingest/camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf/audio_1.pcm', dir='camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf', filename='audio_1.pcm', volume='default', nlvl_from=1, nlvl_to=1.Set enable_drefs to allow this.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Skipped opening external track: stream 3, alias: path='/VibrintAVFiles/P2 News Ingest/camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf/audio_2.pcm', dir='camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf', filename='audio_2.pcm', volume='default', nlvl_from=1, nlvl_to=1.Set enable_drefs to allow this.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Skipped opening external track: stream 4, alias: path='/VibrintAVFiles/P2 News Ingest/camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf/audio_3.pcm', dir='camb_onitefire_050914(1).vmf', filename='audio_3.pcm', volume='default', nlvl_from=1, nlvl_to=1.Set enable_drefs to allow this.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe1fb000000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: dvvideo (dvpp / 0x70707664), none, 720x576, 28800 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'camb_onitefire_050914.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
  Duration: 00:17:47.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dvvideo (dvpp / 0x70707664), none, 720x576, 28800 kb/s, SAR 118:81 DAR 295:162, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 2500 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:46:43:02
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:5(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-04T18:54:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Handle Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:46:43:02
File 'camb_onitefire_A.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
Finishing stream 0:1 without any data written to it.
Nothing was written into output file 0 (camb_onitefire_A.mp4), because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 0x7fe1fd010e00] Qavg: nan
```

Heres an example of the file structure of this novel mxd:

[image: mxf example]

Comment: You are forcing a demuxer, not a decoder. Show the console output for your original command. Also your input is MOV, not MXF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a MOV which is only a shell and the actual streams are elsewhere.

Run

```
ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i camb_onitefire_050914.mov camb_onitefire_A.mp4
```

Run, to transfer all tracks

```
ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i camb_onitefire_050914.mov -map 0:v -map 0:a camb_onitefire_A.mp4
```

The above, with timecode

```
ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i camb_onitefire_050914.mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_onitefire_A.mp4
```

Comment: Oh wow that seems to be working great! Thank you. My next step is to map the 4 discreet mono audio tracks across to the mp4. As I think that ffmpeg will default to using only the first stream/channel?

Comment: Sadly it's looking for an additional stream? [mp4 @ 0x7fb7a981a800] You requested a copy of the original timecode track so timecode metadata are now ignored
[mp4 @ 0x7fb7a981a800] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #5, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:4 --

Comment: Can I not use Stream 5? Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:5 (copy)

Comment: I would prefer the timecode but it seems that h264 doesn't support it? Your amended map command is working now. Is there an alternative for reading the TC? I would be happy to write from just the first frame TC value instead of tracking it all the way through. As some MXF types allow discontinuous TC, I don't care about that.

Comment: a) your input is not MXF !  b) as it is, the timecode in a MOV/MP4 is just the starting frame TC. The editing/player app then generates successive TCs.

Comment: a) Hmm, I guess you're right. I gather that it's a proprietary modification by Grass Valley for their legacy K2 server solution. b) I'm happy to use the timestamp from the first TC value n the side car file but how can I make ffmpeg use that value to create the h264 TC? Oh I see you've modified the answer. Sorry. I'll try now

Comment: That seems to be working quite well thank you. I was wondering though.. I have many files to convert but I assume that the shell/pointer file must reside with the media files in their folder? Do you think ffmpeg would convert from a collection of alias or shortcut files? I could collect them into one place instead of using the media root locations

Comment: I think that this idea won't work because of the Absolute Path command. I cannot place shortcut or alias copies of the shell .mov file because ffmpeg needs to use the local path. This will be annoying, I don't want to create a batch list I'd rather use a drop folder but all the media must stay in its own folders Hmmm

Comment: As long as the full paths are embedded within the shell file, you can place the shells anywhere.

Comment: I have tried this on a Windows machine and get a fault :( My code was : h:\Conversion folder>ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i fdb9_Aerials
EagleFarm_0610.mov -map 0:a -write_tmcd fdb9_AerialsEagleFarm_0610a.mp4                                                         It now says that "Trailing options were found on the commandline" and "unspe
cified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options". Otherwise it seems to recognise the audio and video codec   Should I re-open this question? Or pose a new question?

Comment: Your write_tmcd is missing its value, but the pixel format msg suggests your video stream is malformed. Open  a new Q. Run your command with `-report` and paste the full log file.

Comment: Have posted new Q at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559728/ffmpeg-doesnt-recognize-quicktime-dv-codec