# Can I use ffmpeg in Windows to encode video from another folder?

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is the script that works from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559728/ffmpeg-doesnt-recognize-quicktime-dv-codec):

```
ffmpeg -report -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i fdb9_AerialsEagleFarm_0610.mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 fd9_AerialsEagleFarm_A0609.mp4
```

This works fine but only if ffmpeg is running in the media folder. I cannot use alias or shortcut files to point back to the source media folder? Is there any way to make this point to a relative path?

Perhaps this is un-achievable?
if so is there a way to define a variable entry that only works on a .mov file? As there is only one .mov file I would seek in the media folder this would save me writing the name each time into the script. Could that variable be used in the output name as well?

Comment: AFAIK, drefs only contain Unix-style paths, so on Win, data streams in another folder won't work.  Try this: navigate to the data folder and then execute the command with the full path to the MOV and abs path set to 0.

Comment: I've placed the ffmpeg exe in the media folder above the clip data, but I cannot define the path correctly.... H:\2017\Peter Mc>ffmpeg -report -use_absolute_path 0 -i H:\Conversion folder\cam
b_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_LungDoctor_730
_1403(1).mp4

Comment: BTW ffmpeg runs correctly I just don't know the path structure?

Comment: I tried substituting H:\Conversion folder\camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov for "H:\Conversion folder\camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov". This would process the proxy path but would not find the media in the data folder. At least it doesn't say No File or Directory anymore

Answer (score 0):

I installed ffmpeg in a folder on C: called "ffmpeg" and set "path" as an environment variable pointing at the ffmpeg exe in System>Advanced System Properties.

Confirmed that ffmpeg runs in cmd

I set path to media folder and called the following, making sure to include drefs as it is required to read relative paths of media components I guess.

```
ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 0 -i camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mp4
```

As long as I have cmd looking at the media folder it works but if I want to run from C: and make the media directory using explicit SET PATH it won't run ffmpeg. I don't know why.

```
C:\Users\MYNAME>SET PATH=%PATH%;"H:\2017\PeterMc\camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).vmf\" ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 0 -i camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mp4
```